# how to fix return in recursive function?

Tags: c++

I made a recursive function that calculates factorial.
When the values ​​of a and b == int everything is OK. BUT when I changed the value of b to long double, everything broke.

Where did I make a mistake?

gives -nan (ind) instead of result

error in return?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long double factorial(int, long double);

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "enter number: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    long double b = 1.0; 

    cout << "\n factorial " << a << " = " << factorial(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}

long double factorial(int a, long double b)
{
    if (a && (a - 1))
    {

        b = b * a * (a - 1);
        cout << "a:" << a << " b: " << b << endl;

        a = a - 2;
        factorial(a, b);

    }
    else if ((a - 1) == 0) { cout << "b final return = " << b; return b; }
}
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY3Ib.png)

Comment: Hint: What does your function return if `a && (a - 1);`?

Comment: Why are you using this really obscure way to calculate a factorial?

Comment: The flashy `if (a && (a - 1))` is not portable until C++20.

Comment: Why are you ignoring compiler warnings?

Comment: Why `(a - 1) == 0` and not `a == 1`? Also, `a && (a - 1)` is not equivalent to `a > 1` and will ultimately lead to undefined behaviour if you pass a negative number. (It looks like you're trying to beat the compiler's optimisations by being clever. That almost never works.)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!
I recently started learning c ++ from a book. And while I feel insecure in the code. Such a strange code is caused by an error in ide that I did not understand and decided to get around by making the code larger.
Now I figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these:

- A function whose return type isn't `void` must always return a value. Your function has no return statement in the `if` branch, nor outside the if-statement. As a consequence, the behaviour of the program is undefined if the branch is ever entered. To fix this, you must add a return statement.
- Considering the function has no side-effects, calling it is entirely pointless unless you use the returned value. Your intention may be to `return factorial(a, b);`, which makes the call useful, and fixes the lack of return statement mentioned previously.
- Also, the function lacks another return statement if neither the first if branch, nor the else-if branch is entered.

---

```
(a - 1) == 0
```

That's one unnecessarily complicated way of expressing `a == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
factorial(a, b);
```

should be

```
return factorial(a, b);
```

Your version calls the factorial recursively but does nothing with the result. You need to return the result of the recursive call from the current call.